# How to access individual arguments of args passed to decorated function

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I am trying to decorate 5 functions with an exception handling function. Each decorated function is to accept a differing number of parameters but all will have  one important parameter in common, fname. I'd like to use that common parameter, as example shows below.

This comes close but I can't get to fname:

```
def mydeco(func):
    
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    
        print(args)
        #print(fname) <== this fails as well;
        #Unwrapping args gives 'SyntaxError: can't use starred expression here'
               
        try:
            print('Before func')
            answer = func(*args,**kwargs)
            print('after func in wrapper')
            if answer == 2:
                print(f"Great job {fname}")
        except Exception as e:
            print('blah', e)
    
    return wrapper


@mydeco
def long(fname, lname):
    print(f"hello {fname} {lname}")
    return 2

@mydeco
def short(fname):
    print(f"hello {fname}")



short('Bob')
long('Bob', 'Smith')

('Bob',)
Before func
hello Bob
after func in wrapper
('Bob', 'Smith')
Before func
hello Bob Smith
after func in wrapper
blah name 'fname' is not defined
```

Am I way off?

Comment: "args" is just a tuple, if it isn't empty, take its first item. If it is empty, use the key "fname" in dictionary "kwargs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper function's parameters are `*args` and `**kwargs`. The `lname` and `fname` parameters are not defined in wrapper outside of the inner functions.

In this function call

> long('Bob', 'Smith')

the ***positional arguments*** are passed as an ****args tuple***. They can be accessed in wrapper as follows: `args[0]` and `args[1]`.

Alternatively, if you change the function call to

> long(fname = 'Bob', lname = 'Smith')

then the ***keyword arguments*** will be passed as a *****kwargs dictionary***. They can be accessed as follows: `kwargs['fname']` and `kwargs['lname']`.

Answer (score 1):

args is non keyword argument under a tuple
kwargs is Keyword Arguments under a dictionary

It also depends on purpose which one will be used, in the wrapper function you need to access to them accordingly.

```
long('Bob', 'Smith') # args = ('Bob', 'Smith') kargs = []
long(fname='Bob',lname='Smith') # args = () kargs= ['fname':'Bob', 'lname'='Smith']
```